# When formula result changes in cell, macro doesn't run. Why?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, method-call

When formula result changes in my table in column K range ("K2:K5") I want the entire row in the table to be filled with a color. But I only want the row to be colored if the result is not equal to 0.

So eg. if the result changes in K2 (and is not = 0) the entire row A2:L2 will be colored.
The formula are refering to values that you select from dropdown-lists (created from "data validation" on the excel menu Data-tab). These dropdowns are located on the same row  (eg. “D2:J2”) as the related formula. The values in the dropdown is refering to a range on the same sheet outside of the table.
So far I have one code for the worksheet concerning the change event that calls the module with the  sub that will change the color on the row.

But it doesn't work and I get no error messages.

This is the code for the worksheet change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "§D2:§J2" Then
Color_Row
End If

End Sub
```

Here the target address should propably be the whole range, but I don't know how to give the right syntax for that.

Here is the code for changing color on row:

```
Sub Color_Row()
Dim r As Long, c As Long 'r=rows in the excel sheet | c= value of cell in _  
column k
Dim numrow As Long 'last row with data
Dim tblR As Long 'tablerow

numrow = TimeMeasure.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To numrow
tblR = r - 1
c = Cells(r, 11).Value

If c <> 0 Then
      [TimeDist].Rows(tblR).Interior.Color = 12961279

Else

      [TimeDist].Rows(tblR).Interior.Color = xlNone 'no fill color


End If

Next

End Sub
```

I have steped in to this code and watched variables like c, r, numrow, tblR and it all seems to match my table (the name of my table is TimeDist).

The only thing that I've noticed is that no values ever assigns to c in the loop. I know though that this code works in another workbook, but then I manualy type in a new value in a specific cell outside of the table, which changes the formula result in table (then the rows get colored)

I very thankfuly accept any help on this.

Comment: Work_sheet change will not fire on a cell change due to formula change. You will want worksheet_calculate.

Comment: For an example of how to use worksheet_calculate for this, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56137635/automatically-enter-date-time-as-cell-is-updated-changed

Comment: Note that `"§D2:§J2"` is no valid address it must be `"$D2:$J2"` using the dollar sign `$` not the section sign `§`!

Comment: Many thanks for all your inputs which has helped me to solve it! :) See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all your inputs which has helped me to solve it! :)

It now works like a charm!

This worksheet_calculate code does the job (I have changed my cell range though):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Xrg As Range
Set Xrg = Range("L2:L5")
If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("L2:L5")) Is Nothing Then
Color_Row
End If
End Sub
```